# Converting Ajax/jQuery Post function to just jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is my original function.  it works perfectly, I just want to compress it a bit:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
function searchmusic(){
var ajaxRequest;  

try{
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e){
            alert('Your browser broke!');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('searchresults');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

    }
}
var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
var params = 'search=' + search;
ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'getsearch.php', true);  
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajaxRequest.send(params);

}
</script>
```

I am trying to compress this function a bit, so i have tried to duplicate it using jQuery:

```
 <script>
 function searchmusic(){
 var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
 $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: getsearch.php,
async: true,
data: 'search=' + search,
success: function(data) {
$('#searchresults').load(data);
 }
 });
 }
</script>
```

However, I can not get this function to work properly.  Could someone please tell me where I have made the mistake, and why this function is not working, or it could be that this new function can not function as my original one did.  I don't know, but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're missing quotes around your url. is that a copy/past problem or is it in the code?

Comment: @Ariel. 10 seconds ahead... :)

Comment: That is my fault, I forgot the quotes.  I added them and the function still does not seem to work.

Comment: While we're it, you can compress it even more by removing `async: true` because that's the default behavior, or replace $.ajax with $.post ;)

Comment: We can compress even a *lot* more with `.load` (details in my answer), if used in the correct manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url: getsearch.php,
```

should be

```
url: 'getsearch.php',
```

and

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#searchresults').load(data);
}
```

should be

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#searchresults').html(data);
}
```

And also `var search = document.getElementById('search').value;` is ok but as because you are using `jQuery` so you can use `var search = $('#search').val()` instead and by default `async is true` so you could ommit it and also `$.ajax` could be `$.post` so you can remove `type: 'POST'` too.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
url: getsearch.php, // The property php of the getsearch variable
```

To:

```
url: 'getsearch.php', // A string with the URL.
```

And change:

```
$('#searchresults').load(data);
```

To:

```
$('#searchresults').html(data);
```

Comment: I did that and it still does not seem to work, but thanks for that info, as it was obviously one problem with my script.

Comment: @Eggo. Change the `load` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Waaaay more compact:

```
function searchmusic(){
 $("#searchresult").load("getsearch.php", {search: $("#search").val()});
}
```

That's all your function needs :)

You can use `.load()` whenever an AJAX result should go inside an element. The parameters passed as object ensure we do a POST and not a GET call.
So your function can be trimmed down a lot.